# Scale range slider for ionic framework

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, ionic-framework

Looking for range scale slider in ionic framework. Found this link http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#styling-scale. But its not like we want. The handle should stop on center and ruler will move with touch. How can i achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Im also expect this same. If possible pls share me your code.